# Is a polynomial monotone when the first derivative has only imaginary roots?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I have a polynomial over a specific the range. The first derivative has only two imaginary roots and no real roots. The first derivative is positive in the lower bound and upper bound. Does that mean that the function is monotone (increasing) over the range?

Comment: Consider $(x^2+1)(x-3)$ over $[0,3]$. What is $f'(1)$?

Comment: For the new version of your question, if the derivative doesn't have real roots, there can be no change of sign, which implies it is increasing everywhere. This remains true even if you restrict it to any specific interval.  BTW, you need to clearly state the problem (not amend it significantly a day later) and provide your own thoughts / attempts at solving it if you want helpful answers at this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. The first derivative being positive at the lower and upper bounds of the range indicates that the function is increasing at those points. However, the function could still have other critical points within the range where it changes direction.

For instance, consider a polynomial with two imaginary roots within the specified range. While the first derivative is positive at the lower and upper bounds, there could be a local minimum or maximum within the range where the derivative is zero or undefined, causing the function to change direction.

To determine if the function is monotone over the entire range, you need to analyze the behavior of the first derivative and check for any additional critical points (where the derivative is zero or undefined) within the range. If there are no such critical points, then the function would indeed be monotone over that range.

Comment: I'm not really sure that this answered your original question , if it did not please explain it a bit more and I can help you further

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please note that the first derivative is not zero at any real point in the range. It just has two imaginary roots. So, can I say that it is monotone now?

Comment: if the first derivitive is continues, non zero and we know it's positive somewhere, what can we tell about it.....? If it has holes in its graph it's another story though

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x):=2x^3-9x^2+12x$. Then $f(x)$ has just one real zero, at $x=0$, the other two being complex. Also, its gradient $f'(x)=6(x^2-3x+2)=6(x-1)(x-2)$ is $12$ at $x=0$ and $x=3$, while it has a maximum at $x=1$ and a minimum at $x=2$. So it is not monotone in the range $0$ to $3$, while having a positive gradient at both ends of this range.

**Answer to revised question:** The derivative of a polynomial is also a polynomial. If this latter polynomial has only two imaginary roots and no real root, then it is either a quadratic or (if multiple roots are allowed) a power of a quadratic. In the real domain, a quadratic function that never takes the value zero is either always positive or always negative. So, in this case, the gradient is always positive. That is, the original polynomial is strictly increasing (and so monotone) everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your example is correct but different from what I asked. The first derivative of my function equals to zero gives only two imaginary points. So, there is no real local minimum or maximum in the range.

Comment: @sonia Your comment is very different from your question.  You did not mention in your question that the **derivative** of the function had **only** two imaginary roots.  You should correct the question if that is so.

Comment: Thank. I corrected the question. could you please answer that now?

Comment: @sonia : Please see my appended answer to your revised question.